# Wordpress Link Items to Display in Parent Sidebar

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have created a menu like so... http://tinyurl.com/p5xr852

You can see I have added links under "What's Happening?" which I want to use as page anchors from a sidebar.

What I need to do is have these items list in a sidebar when on the parent page.

I have done a heap of research and found that `wp_get_links` is now deprecated (see here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_links)

Apparently this has now been replaced with `wp_list_bookmarks()`

Is there any way what so ever to do this? I don't want to go down the route of creating a heap of multiple menu's as I will be adding these links under post pages to act as page anchors.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood correctly. You want that list of links displaying on the sidebar, when the user is in "What's Happening" -page OR any of it's child-pages?

If I didin't understand then just skip this but.

Create a new text widget that has your pages as a list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">etc</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">etc</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">etc</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">etc</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then get the Widget Logic plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/
This plugin allows you to choose where widgets appear, for example in certain pages, in archives, in certain languages, in child-pages etc. 
Check out: http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/other_notes/ on how to make this link-list-navigation-widget to appear on the pages you want it to.

It's something like

```
global $post; return (is_page('15') || ($post->post_parent=="15"));
```

You put the ID of the page on which you want the widget to appear on. And its child-pages with the latter.

Comment: Is there anyway of writing this without using plugins and widgets? I don't understand how you can pull out pages using something as simple as....

<?php
    if($post->post_parent)
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
    else
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
    if ($children) { ?>
    <ul class="sub-nav">
    <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php } ?>

But you cant pull links the same way?

Comment: OK. I have gor the full navigation pulling out with the links now using this

<?php
    if($post->post_parent)
    $children = wp_nav_menu("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
    else
    $children = wp_nav_menu("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
    if ($children) { ?>
    <ul class="sub-nav">
    <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php } ?>


SO, what I need now is just add depth, for displaying second level only. And then make it conditional, so when on a parent page, it's own second level links